# saving in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm having a problem on how/where I can save my `NSUserDefaults` for `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillTerminate`, I need to save my `NSArray` count in `NSUserDefaults` from another `UIViewController` when user exits the app or enter background. But I don't know if I would save the right `integer`, because my `NSArray` count is being updated when I am deleting on it on `UIView`. 
I cant save it on `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`. Hope someone would help. Thankyou.

Comment: Are you using more than 1 thread than?

Answer (score 1):

If u need to save from another ViewController then its better u add `NSMutableArray` in appDelegate. Whenever you delete or add object then save the count of array as it will overwrite like this:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[yourArray count] forKey:@"Count"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Retrieve like this:**

```
 NSInteger count = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Count"];
```

**EDIT** : `synchronize` : Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk and updates all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk.

Refer [NSUserDefaults_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as clearly states gets called perodically and we don't have to wait for their call

Comment: Its update is on adding on array, and deleting on array. I will put the saving in NSUserDefaults in every part?

Comment: Certainly don't call synchronize every time. You likely don't need to call synchronize at all, but being killed on memory pressure can make that tricky on iOS.

Comment: @Catfish_Man Refer [NSUserDefaults_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as it clearly states gets called perodically and we don't have to wait for their call

Answer (score 0):

Create the required NSMutableArray in your appDelegate class i.e create a property of NSMutableArray iVar,then later you can update ,add ,delete contents from it in any of the classes.Thus you shall get the array count in the applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillTerminate notification functions in the appDelegate function itself and the array count should be accurate..

in yourAppDelegate.h

create ..

```
    @interface yourAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *myArray;
    }
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *myArray; //replace strong by retain if ios <5
```

in yourAppDelegate.m

@synthesize myArray;

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *
)launchOptions{
     self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

further in your required functions in appDelegate.m file

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.myArray count] forKey:@"myOwnKey"]];
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

in case if you want to add objects to this array in any other class just create a delegate of the yourAppDelegate .

Eg in viewDidLoad of class A,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{  // assuming viewController A

YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplicatio sharedApplication]delegate];
[appDelegate.myArray addObject:@"1232"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to save value to `NSUserDefaults`

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:yourArray forKey:@"YourKey"]
[defaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

For details on using NSUserDefault check this

- `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:<#(BOOL)#> forKey:<#(NSString *)#>]`, this Is for Boolean you an add `setInt/setFloat/SetDouble etc` and even *ObjectiveC* `objects` with `setValue/setObject`.

  ```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:<#(id)#> forKey:<#(NSString *)#>];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:<#(id)#> forKey:<#(NSString *)#>];
  ```
- To retrieve the value you can use `getters` like `boolForKey` (`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:<#(NSString *)#>]`) `intForKey etc.`.
- Use `removeObjectForKey` to remove objects.